# Cannot find property 'filter' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I have set up my online shop project (Angular) and been trying to do some sort of "Recommendations" area in each product page.

At first I wanted to subscrible all of my products, and then going over them in order to find matching type and id.

Just for testing, I've created 18 products(6 different products) in my MongoDB (3 products of the same product with the same type and id), but unfortunately received this error and cannot figure out why:

**Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined
    at ProductComponent.findRecommandedProducts**

```js
export class ProductComponent implements OnInit {

  recommandedProducts: Product[];
  allProducts: Product[];
  product: Product;


  constructor(private productService: ProductService, private route: Router, private actRoute: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.recommandedProducts = this.findRecommandedProducts(this.product)
  };

  findRecommandedProducts(currectProduct: Product){
    this.productService.getProducts().subscribe((data: Product[]) => {
      this.allProducts = data;
    });
//productService.getProducts() returns all of my products in JSON format to localhost//

    let recommandedProducts = this.allProducts.filter(otherProduct => 
      otherProduct.type == currectProduct.type && otherProduct.id == currectProduct.id) 

      // otherProduct.id == currectProduct.id becacuse i have 3 identical items of each item. //
      
      return recommandedProducts;
  };

}
```

Comment: Hello moses, welcome to StackOverflow! You need to do your filtering inside the .subscribe() code block. That is the place that you know for sure you have received an answer from your backend/service/data provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to move code as below:

```
export class ProductComponent implements OnInit {

  recommandedProducts: Product[];
  allProducts: Product[];
  product: Product = {type: "something" , id: 1};


  constructor(private productService: ProductService, private route: Router, private actRoute: ActivatedRoute) { }


  ngOnInit() {
    this.findRecommandedProducts(this.product)
  };

  findRecommandedProducts(currectProduct: Product){
    this.productService.getProducts().subscribe((data: Product[]) => {
      this.allProducts = data;
      this.recommandedProducts = this.allProducts.filter(otherProduct => 
      otherProduct.type == currectProduct.type && otherProduct.id == currectProduct.id) 
    });  
  };

}
```

**Reason:**

You are listening to observable using `this.productService.getProducts()`, so your `this.allProducts` will be populated asynchronously, hence the `.filter` won't work on `undefined`. Move it to `subscribe` block, so now once you have `this.allProducts` , you can use `.filter()`.

1. make sure `this.product` is `defined` , in the given code it has been declared and not initialized.
2. `this.recommandedProducts = this.findRecommandedProducts(this.product)` will also not work. Please read more about the way to work with `observable` (these are async operations, so your function has to be written in that way)

Comment: Thank you for help! It sure helped, yet now i get this error: 
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined for : 
 otherProduct.type == currectProduct.type && otherProduct.id == currectProduct.id)

Comment: @moses: As I mentioned, you need to initialize `product: Product = {type: "something" , id: 1}` . refer point number `1`

Comment: I did that in my Product Schema, Product.ts file and in my database,
as you can see them displayed in my front page: https://imgur.com/D64k6y3

Comment: @moses : No, You need to do it on component level inside the `class` of typescript. Can you do changes as mentioned in my newly changed code. Do changes accordingly and let me know that the error has been fixed. Meanwhile, how are you initializing the value in `product.ts` and using it in `product-component.ts`. Share the code of `product.ts`

Comment: I really appreciate you help, but I figured out that the issue is filtering an observable using rxjs filter, which I failed to do..

Comment: @moses : I doubt that you shared that part of code. Happy coding.